# Error when using roll_regres from rollRegres: Assertion on 'width' failed

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a rolling regression on daily stock data using `rollRegres::roll_regres`. I was having trouble reading in the data so the program is a little unique. I had to put the data into a matrix as the function kept insisting on a matrix. Here is the relevant part of the program and some data. The error message I get is:

> ```
> Error in roll_regres.fit(x = x, y = y, width = width, do_compute = do_compute,  : 
>   Assertion on 'width' failed: Element 1 is not <= 2
> ```

Program:

```r
for( i in 2:16384)  {
    return <- data[,..i]
    return <- as.matrix(return)
    Data2 <- merge(data, dataf,by="date")
    Data3 <- data.frame(return,Data2$mkt)
    Data4 <- as.matrix(Data3)
    Data5 <- na.omit(Data4)
    beta <- roll_regres(Data5[1,] ~ Data5[2,] , width=720,do_downdates=TRUE,min_obs=720)
    tail(beta$coefs)
    beta.mat[d:(d + rows - 1),] <- beta
    ret.id[d:(d + rows - 1),] <- i
    d <- d + rows
}
```

Data:

```
[1722,]  0.000000      0.28
[1723,] -0.025000     -0.32
[1724,]  0.025641      0.79
[1725,] -0.025000     -0.50
[1726,]  0.000000     -0.47
[1727,]  0.000000      0.44
[1728,] -0.025641      0.03
[1729,]  0.052632      0.35
[1730,] -0.025000      0.17
[1731,] -0.025641      0.86
[1732,]  0.026316      0.08
[1733,]  0.025641      0.00
[1734,] -0.050000     -0.33
[1735,]  0.052632     -0.40
[1736,] -0.033333      0.81
[1737,] -0.017241      0.23
[1738,]  0.008772      0.68
[1739,]  0.008696     -0.28
[1740,]  0.000000      0.60
[1741,]  0.017241      0.41
[1742,] -0.016949      0.24
[1743,] -0.008621      0.34
[1744,]  0.017391     -0.06
[1745,] -0.025641     -0.21
[1746,]  0.026316      0.06
[1747,]  0.000000      0.51
[1748,]  0.010769      0.64
[1749,] -0.025641      0.32
[1750,]  0.000000     -0.29
[1751,]  0.000000     -0.32
[1752,]  0.000000     -0.17
[1753,]  0.035088     -0.17
[1754,] -0.033898     -0.18
[1755,] -0.017544     -0.37
[1756,]  0.017857      0.88
[1757,] -0.017544      1.10
[1758,]  0.035714     -0.08
[1759,] -0.017241     -0.06
[1760,]  0.000000     -0.14
[1761,] -0.017544      0.19
[1762,]  0.000000     -0.06
[1763,]  0.017857     -0.05
[1764,]  0.000000      0.20
[1765,] -0.017544     -0.18
[1766,]  0.035714     -0.30
[1767,] -0.017241     -0.19
[1768,]  0.000000      0.14
[1769,]  0.017544     -0.77
[1770,]  0.000000     -0.40
[1771,]  0.000000      0.41
[1772,] -0.017241      0.00
[1773,] -0.035088      0.50
[1774,]  0.000000      0.73
[1775,]  0.018182      0.36
[1776,]  0.000000      0.01
[1777,] -0.017857     -0.27
[1778,]  0.036364     -0.27
[1779,]  0.000000      0.43
[1780,] -0.035088      0.25
[1781,]  0.018182      0.74
[1782,]  0.000000      0.02
[1783,] -0.017857     -0.54
[1784,]  0.018182     -0.02
[1785,]  0.000000      0.11
[1786,] -0.017857      0.84
[1787,]  0.000000      0.14
[1788,]  0.018182      0.95
[1789,]  0.000000      0.55
[1790,]  0.000000     -0.33
[1791,] -0.017857     -0.21
[1792,]  0.036364     -0.66
[1793,] -0.035088      0.20
[1794,]  0.018182      0.30
[1795,]  0.017857     -0.61
[1796,] -0.017544     -2.71
[1797,]  0.000000     -0.43
[1798,]  0.017857     -0.17
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Thanks for including a dataset and some sample code, but it would be more likely that people help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example. Looking at your code there are some variables such as `dataf` that are not defined.

Comment: Thanks, I already solved the problem

Comment: @KLow45 can you describe how?